# Using Irdroid with a raspberry

Tags: remote

I am new on this forum, and I hope that my question may not seem too "easy" for you.

I recently purchased an Irdroid transceiver in order to turn my Raspberry Pi into to remote control for my Samsung TV.

I followed several tutorials, but they don't really deal with an Irdroid, they either deal with "classic" IR receivers or USB IR toy (which supposedly uses a driver compatible with Irdroid). So here what I tried :
I found the tty number of my Irdroid using 'dmesg'
I then use the following command line to record my remote control : 'irrecord -n -H irman -d /dev/ttyACM0 Example.conf'

When I am asked to point the remote control and press any button, the Irdroid seems to detect the signal (there is a blue light blinking), but nothing happens on the Raspberry terminal.

Could someone help me please ? Don't hesitate if you would need more details.

Comment: Can you try irrecord with -D 10 option and post what you get?

Comment: I am sorry, I am a beginner with LIRC...
Do you mean 'irrecord -D 10' ? If then, I get 'invalid option'.
If I try typing 'irrecord -d 10 option', I get 'could not get file information for 10', 'No such file or directory' and 'could not init hardware.